# Different colours for segments of a polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a polyline and I want to colourise each line between two points depending on its length. What are my options? I found no way to do that on a single object and the lines I have to work with have up to 15,000 points, so generating fifteen thousand single lines of different colours isn't particularly efficient.

Comment: A polyline has a single color.  I don't know of any other options other than making each color you need a single polyline, multiple polylines if the segments are disjoint.

Comment: Are your Polylines built using static data or some form of data that remains good for a time period? Or do you have to dynamically create your Polylines using dynamically queried data?

Comment: The lines are loaded from a file, then the user can dynamically move the vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Polyline Options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions) state that there's one `strokeColor` for a polyline. You'd have to do it yourself, manually. You could probably automate the process, slightly, by building a function that takes an array of points, calculates the distance between the first 2, decides the color, creates a polyline, then moves on to the next point. Rinse and repeat. Yeah, 15K points is going to be slow, although I suspect that even calling GMaps API with a 15K array of LatLng isn't that fast either...